# Is it possible to format/create a partition from a UWP application?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

I've created an application that deals with low level disc operations in WPF. I would consider porting it to UWP, but I think that this platform is strongly sandboxed and doesn't support operations that require elevation (running as admin).

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the 1809 update for Windows 10 (SDK build 17763) this is now possible thanks to the introduction of the 'allowElevation' capability for UWP.

With this capability your UWP app package can include Win32 EXEs that you launch as elevated in order to perform tasks that require administrative privileges on desktop.

I have a tutorial for this on my blog:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/01/app-elevation-samples-part-1/